# How to Implement Search functionality on multiple ArrarAdapters

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-search

Hello I am trying to implement the search functionality. I have a `SearchResultActivity` class that extends `ListActivity`. I have also edited my `AndroidManifest` file to indicate a new activity. I have two different arrays, with different lengths and more are still coming. I have been surfing the net on how to retrieve the data from `ListView` but I haven't got the search function running. Please review all my codes below and let me know what I need to do or probably doing wrong. Still very new developer on Android and Java. So a nice and easy solution would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class SearchResultActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}
private void showResults(String query) {
    /*SearchResultActivity.this.adapterBike.getFilter().filter(query);*/
    //SearchResultActivity.this.adapterCar.getFilter().filter(query);
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}

@Override
public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setListAdapter(adapter);

}
}
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {     
ListView allLists;    
SearchView searchView;    
CarSublist carSublist;
BikeSublist bikeSublist;
ArrayAdapter adapterBike;
ArrayAdapter adapterCar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    adapterBike = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.BikeList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    adapterCar = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.CarList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);        
    allLists = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.all_list);

}   

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_page, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(
            new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SearchResultActivity.class)));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        //decided to work on the firstArray
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
           String[] bikeArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.BikeList);
            String[] carArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CarList);

            for (String data : bikeArray){
                if (data.equals(query) ){
                    //do Something
                    bikeSublist = new BikeSublist();
                    bikeSublist.bindData();
                }else{
                 break;
                }
            }

            HomePage.this.adapterBike.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //decided to work on the firstArray
            String[] bikeArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.BikeList);
            for (String data : bikeArray){
                if (data.equals(newText) ){
                    HomePage.this.adapterBike.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    bikeSublist = new BikeSublist();
                    bikeSublist.bindData();
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;

        }
    });

    return true;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Create your own Filter for searching in adapter class like below

```
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;
private ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist;

        public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            worldpopulationlist.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
            } 
            else 
            {
                for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist) 
                {
                    if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
                    {
                        worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

and apply it on your edittext:

```
// Capture Text in EditText
        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is link for the same

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: No it did not. I have seen this tutorial and tried it before asking my question. But I am very grateful for your response. I was able to implement some of your codes and used it on mine. I will try and post my result when I ma done with it. Thanks Anjali

Comment: let me know what an issue that you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is what I did. And it might be needful for someone later( I guess).
On my fragment, I wrote this line of codes

```
public void bindData(String strSearchText) {
    Object[] arrayItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.BikeList);
    if (strSearchText != null && strSearchText.length() > 0) {
        List<Object> lstFilteredItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object item : arrayItems) {
            if (((String)item).contains(strSearchText)) {
                lstFilteredItems.add(item);
            }
        }
        arrayItems = lstFilteredItems.toArray();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_sub_list,R.id.topText,arrayItems);
    //ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.BikeList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

and then on my activity page, this what I did.

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String strSearchText) {

    myFragment.bindData(strSearchText);
    return true;
}
```

Any idea on how to implement this in multiple fragment is appreciated. Thanks.